# setDefaultTextAttributes on UITextField does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem assigning text attributes (font,color, kerning) to an empty UITextField. Here is some sample code:

```
// testinput is an UITextField created in storyboard
//
 [testinput setDefaultTextAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}  ];
```

That should - in theory - change font & color, but nothing happens. I've also tried different ways of creating the dictionary, no change. Please do not advise to use an attributed string, the UITextField must be initially empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution after reading Gregs comment.
To set the initial attributes in an empty UITextField, use the

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *typingAttributes
```

property. It must be set in one of the delegate methods of the UITextField:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
   NSDictionary* d = textField.typingAttributes;
   NSMutableDictionary* md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:d];

   md[NSFontAttributeName] = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
   md[NSKernAttributeName] = @(9.5f);

   textField.typingAttributes = md;
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use setDefaultTextAttributes the changes will apply to textAttribute not text property of UITextField. So if you want to use text property, and I assume you want you should use, try:

```
testinput.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0];
testinput.textColor = [UIColor redColor]
```

//Extended

I'm afraid you cannot use it in the way you want.
This is from apple documentation:

```
By default, this property returns a dictionary of text attributes with default values.
Setting this property applies the specified attributes to the entire text of the text field. Unset attributes maintain their default values.
```

It looks like when you use defaultTextAttributes property you will get only a dictionary and f you want to set it you have to create attribute string with attributes(dictionaries):

Comment: Yes, of course that works. Unfortunately I need to set different kerning values, which requires the usage of either attributed text or (my preferred method) to set the default text attribute. Since the text field is in my case initially empty, I can't set the kerning with an attributed string. So I'm left with setDefaultTextAttribute which does not seem to work at all. I cannot even change the font color with that.

Comment: @ThomasZimmer see extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 version**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentAttributes = textField.typingAttributes
    if var attributes = currentAttributes {
        attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue] = UIColor.white
        attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue] = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
        textField.typingAttributes = attributes
    }

    return true
}
```